# How can I make an Idempotent Callable Function with Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, idempotent

Sometimes I'm getting duplicated documents from a callable function that looks like this:

```js
const { default: Big } = require('big.js');
const { firestore } = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { createLog } = require('./utils/createLog');
const { payCart } = require('./utils/payCart');
const { unlockCart } = require('./utils/unlockCart');

exports.completeRechargedTransaction = functions.https.onCall(
  async (data, context) => {
    try {
      if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          'unauthenticated',
          'unauthenticated'
        );
      }

      const requiredProperties = [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'etc'
      ];

      const isDataValid = requiredProperties.every(prop => {
        return Object.keys(data).includes(prop);
      });

      if (!isDataValid) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          'failed-precondition',
          'failed-precondition'
        );
      }

      const transactionRef = firestore()
        .collection('transactions')
        .doc(data.transactionID);

      const userRef = firestore().collection('users').doc(data.paidBy.userID);

      let currentTransaction = null;

      await firestore().runTransaction(async transaction => {
        try {
          const transactionSnap = await transaction.get(transactionRef);

          if (!transactionSnap.exists) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
              'not-found',
              'not-found'
            );
          }

          const transactionData = transactionSnap.data();

          if (transactionData.status !== 'recharged') {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
              'invalid-argument',
              'invalid-argument'
            );
          }

          if (transactionData.type !== 'recharge') {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
              'invalid-argument',
              'invalid-argument'
            );
          }

          if (transactionData.paidBy === null) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
              'invalid-argument',
              'invalid-argument',
            );
          }

          const userSnap = await transaction.get(userRef);

          if (!userSnap.exists) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
              'not-found',
              'not-found',
            );
          }

          const userData = userSnap.data();

          const newUserPoints = new Big(userData.points).plus(data.points);

          if (!data.isGoldUser) {
            transaction.update(userRef, {
              points: parseFloat(newUserPoints.toFixed(2))
            });
          }

          currentTransaction = {
            ...data,
            remainingBalance: parseFloat(newUserPoints.toFixed(2)),
            status: 'completed'
          };

          transaction.update(transactionRef, currentTransaction);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          throw error;
        }
      });

      const { paymentMethod } = data.rechargeDetails;

      let cashAmount = 0;

      if (paymentMethod && paymentMethod.paymentMethod === 'cash') {
        cashAmount = data.points;
      }

      let cartResponse = null;

      if (
        data.rechargeDetails.isProcessingCart &&
        Boolean(data.paidBy.userID) &&
        !data.isGoldUser
      ) {
        cartResponse = await payCart(context, data.paidBy.userID, cashAmount); 
        // This is the function that does all the writes and for some reason it is getting
        // called twice or thrice in some rare cases, and I'm pretty much sure that 
        // The Angular Client is only calling this function "completeRechargedTransaction " once.
      }

      await createLog({
        message: 'Success',
        createdAt: new Date(),
        type: 'activity',
        collectionName: 'transactions',
        callerID: context.auth.uid || null,
        docID: transactionRef.id
      });

      return {
        code: 200,
        message: 'Success',
        transaction: currentTransaction,
        cartResponse
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);

      await unlockCart(data.paidBy.userID);

      await createLog({
        message: error.message,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        type: 'error',
        collectionName: 'transactions',
        callerID: context.auth.uid || null,
        docID: data.transactionID,
        errorSource:
          'completeRechargedTransaction'
      });

      throw error;
    }
  }
);
```

I'm reading a lot of firebase documentation, but I can't find a solution to implement idempotency on my callable functions, the context parameter in callable function is very different from background functions and triggers, the callable context looks like this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext

I did find a helpful blogpost to implement idempotency with firebase triggers:

[Cloud Functions pro tips: Building idempotent functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions)

But I don't fully understand this approach because I think it's assuming that the document writes are made on the client aka the front end application, and I don't really think that's a good approach because is it too reliant on the client and I'm afraid of security issues as well.

So yeah, I would like to know is there's a way to implement Idempotency on Callable Functions, I need something like an [EventID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#eventid) but for callable functions to safely implement payments on my app and third party apis, such as stripe.

I will appreciate any help or hint you can give me.

Comment: Do you have any suitable logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of idempotent functions mainly applies to the automatically triggered Cloud Functions that respond to events such as [a file uploaded to Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) or [document added to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). In these cases, the event triggers the function to be executed, and if the function succeeds, all is well. However, if the function fails, it will get retried automatically which leads to the problems discussed in the [blog post you linked](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions).

In the case of user-triggered cloud functions (a [HTTPS Event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) or [Callable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) cloud function), these are not retried automatically. It is left up to the caller of these functions to choose to handle any errors and whether they are retried by the client calling the function again.

As these user-triggered functions are only executed by your client code, you should check to make sure that `completeRechargedTransaction()` isn't being called more than once. A method of testing this is to supply your own value for Event ID prior to calling the function like so:

```
// using a firebase push ID as a UUID
// could also use someFirestoreCollectionReference.doc().id or uuid()
const eventId = firebase.database.ref().push().key;

completeRechargedTransaction({
  eventId,
  /* ... other data ... */
})
  .then(console.log.bind(null, "Successfully completed recharged transaction:"))
  .catch(console.error.bind(null, "Failed to complete recharged transaction:"));
```

**Note:** One of the most common ways functions will get called twice by the client is because of rerenders where you've updated the state to show a "loading" message and then your call to the function gets made a second time. As an example for React, you would make sure your database call is wrapped in it's own `useEffect()` call.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, I really appreciate it, I ended using a custom eventID generated from the client, to be sure that every function call is unique.

Comment: @samthecodingman Hello sir, Im wondering, if you please, how  would this code : `completeRechargedTransaction({
  eventId,
  /* ... other data ... */
})` 
prevent twice execution. I'm asking to understand it to fix my own function.

Comment: @MostafaOnaizan What you describe is known as *debouncing* a function call. Search "react debounce request" or "react debounce function" for examples. If you are still stuck, ask a separate question with why the other solutions don't suit your needs.

Comment: @samthecodingman I asked a separate question including the function's code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913107/how-to-make-callable-google-cloud-function-idempotent